What are the functions of these capacitors connected to the output of a efuse?
I am a beginner in electronics, and I am studying a LiPo charger circuit:
https://www.elektor.com/products/diy-lipo-supercharger-kit-v2-by-greatscott
This is the full schematic:
https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/elektormagazine/shopify/v59F5q8B9WcWKokvP9xom4TwesJ5q1NQ.pdf
I am particularly confused by the series of capacitors connected to the output of the efuse TPS259621, marked in the red box in the following image.

I read the datasheet of this efuse, which can be found here:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2596.pdf?ts=1720976142460&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.com%252F
It doesn't seems have any particular requirement to the output bypass/decoupling caps.
So what are the functions of each of these cap? How someone go about figure out an appropriate capacitance value for them?
Thank you

C5-C6 as well.  Or, you could equally well ask: why are C3 and C4 equal here?
The topic is PDN (power distribution network) analysis, and I won't go into detail here (as hard as that may be to believe, given the paragraphs below), but I would suggest you play around with simulations, setting up a test jig with representative impedances and seeing what the AC or transient response is.  Key is approximating component, lead and trace lengths as inductance (ballpark 0.5nH/mm of length, but varies with a geometric factor depending on width of the conductor, height above ground or other nearby metal, and so on), and using realistic figures for ESL and ESR of capacitors.
In lieu of a proper pin or simulation model, loads can be modeled as a current or Thevenin source if nothing else.  That is, an operational amplifier might be modeled as a current sink/source, the current varying with load; without loss of generality, we might model these as ideal AC current sources and observe the behavior over a range of frequencies.  The consequence is 1. change in the same node voltage (self impedance), and 2. change in other nodes' voltage (transfer impedance).
Network theory is a somewhat holistic subject: the response of the complete network is sensitive to the value of every component in the network.  There are circumstances where sensitivity (for some components, or at certain frequencies) approaches zero, and we can harness this to ease PDN issues, but in general everything matters, at least what's connected in a local area.
In light of this, asking "the functions of each cap" isn't quite meaningful -- a better question is, what is the function of all of them together?
The effect of staggered value capacitors, is to keep the impedance flatter to higher frequencies.  But you will find, this depends on the size (not just electrical value, but physical size too!) and position of them, and while the impedance might center around a typical value, the peaks and valleys around that value can be quite exaggerated -- due to resonances between capacitors.  These impedance peaks can develop obnoxiously large voltages, and thus affect the operation of loads connected to those nodes.
Finally, regarding C11-C13, the first two more-or-less serve as "fast" bypass, and the electrolytic is "slow" (ESR dominant) and helps to dampen resonance with the others (and, while the eFuse is conductive, to C3-C4 as well).  The dissimilar values might not mean much here, it might depend on what's on the other side of those OUT terminals, it might be for EMI filtering from the regulator (but, this wouldn't do much without an explicit filter inductor between C3/4 and C11-13), etc.  There are many purposes for various component types and values in networks, and there isn't much beyond generalities that we can assume from a schematic alone.
We also shouldn't assume that the designer has done absolutely everything objectively possible.  Engineering is an art form, and where gaps in theory exist, experience -- or imitation -- will take over.  Experience which isn't always properly applied, or is overgeneralized.  In short, people are flawed -- we all have our shortcomings, biases and blind spots.  The only objective function that is universal, is that a product be economically feasible -- and even that only applies to mass-market products.  As such, you see many products on the market that bear clear signs of having evolved -- not in and of themselves as biological evolution, but designs which accumulate cruft: suboptimal solutions to basic problems, vestigial structures, etc.  Evolution doesn't depend upon an intrinsic mechanism, it still works if there's an agent (the engineer) involved.

Thank you very much for the details reply. If I understand you correctly, those capacitor values may not be something you can "derived" for calculation, but rather based on physical measurement/simulation or experience, the designer know that those cap can remove some undesirable frequency from the output voltage?
I never try simulation program, do you think free program like LTSpice would be enough for this kind of simulation. Or do I need a real oscilloscope and components in order to really  understand the topic?

More the merrier; the basics are taught in AC steady-state and signals courses (undergrad EE), but network theory is an advanced topic (graduate/specialized). One doesn't need a complete analytical understanding of the topic to make use of it, just to hint at the contours is enough; just getting a feel for what components go where, and what values are important. By the same token -- it's unlikely (so to say, there's still a possibility) that the designer understood such theory themself, hence the caution at the bottom.

The boost converter TPS61085 has Cout recommendations.  2x10uF is recommended as usually working well.  The loop response is dependent on Cout as well as feedback components, but those relationships are spelled out in the TPS61085 datasheet.  The eFuse chip has a 90mohm nominal resistance, which is outside of the boost converter feedback loop.  The load requirements will dictate what capacitance is required after the efuse.  Tim William's answer describes the C and ESR of each capacitor, as well as why, when you have a high C/high ESR capacitor, you want to parallel that cap with a low ESR capacitor.  There the analysis begins.
